# how to display a table with zero rows in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am loading a content into UITableView dynamically. If there is data the table needs to display the data. If there is no data the table should display a plain page. But in my application the table displays the plain page with two separator lines. i need to remove this separator line and display a plain white page. Please Suggest?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: it's this easy ... [self.tableView setTableFooterView:[UIView new]];

Comment: Note that the actual solution is **simply to set it to be a "grouped" style table**!  To do that, simply go to Thomas Decaux' answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006663/how-can-i-set-a-uitableview-to-grouped-style

Answer (score 26):

If you provide a view to the footer then the separators between the empty rows will disappear.

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
myTableView.tableFooterView = view;
```

Comment: Note that `tableFooterView` is a retained property, so `view` should be (auto)released.

Comment: Works perfectly. Couldn't be simpler.

Comment: Also just to add, you don't need to set frame here. `myTableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init];` is good enough.

Comment: It can be simpler!  :)   **[self.tableView setTableFooterView:[UIView new]];**   Also, why would you make it one pixel high?  if (for some reason) you want to do it the "long" way just make it 0,0,0,0

Answer (score 2):

You could check for the empty case if your datasource is empty add a placeholder view on top of the tableview. If they are not empty, remove the placeholder view.

Comment: Sounds like an ugly hack to me, and ugly hacks tend to break real functionality down the road.

Comment: I believe vice versa: there should be "something" to explain user that application is working as planned, it did not crash, it did already finish what it was doing and - most importantly - this space is empty on purpose, but only for now.

Comment: I don't see why this is an ugly hack, it's just a way of displaying a custom view while there is no data. The custom view can explain why there is no data and how the user can enter data. It's a common practice in iPhone (and Mac) applications.

Answer (score 2):

A plain `UITableView` will always display separator lines even if it is empty. You might notice that if you have a list with only one or two rows, there are still separator lines visible. This is the default behaviour and should not be overridden unless you have a **really** good reason.

I am guessing you see only two separator lines because your rows are very tall?

If you do **really** need to remove the separator lines then set the `separatorStyle` property on your table view to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone`. Take note that this will affect all rows. So if you still want separators for the rows that do exists, then you must draw these separator lines in your own `UITableViewCell` objects.

Answer (score 1):

It can be simplified to a single line, using @bbarnhart solution:

```
myTableView.tableFooterView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

Two steps:

add this code in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    emptyplaceholder = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 100, 640, 100)];
    emptyplaceholder.text = NSLocalizedString(@"No shift changes...", "no shift changes");
    emptyplaceholder.alpha = 0.2;

    [self.view addSubview:emptyplaceholder];

}
```

add this code in controllerDidChangeContent:

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    // The fetch controller has sent all current change notifications, so tell the table view to process all updates.

    if (self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count > 0)
        emptyplaceholder.hidden = YES;
    else
        emptyplaceholder.hidden = NO;

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

so the UILable will disappear when have date cell, when delete to no data in table, the label will show again.

Comment: Sorry, my model is a tableView controller with same date information.

so the words should be:

when the place holder UILabel will hidden when table view have "real" table view cell.

Answer (score 0):

The good UI Design to add a new UIView to the UIViewController when there is no data "No Data available", by adding it will hide separator lines of the UITableView