# how to hide empty rows in a UITableView and change the height of the Uitableview based on non-empty rows

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have couple of problems with my `UITableView`.

1. When I add a `UITableview` on my page, by default it brings up some fixed number of rows,
   even though I set number of rows in section as `1`. All the rows appear except the first row, *and* all are empty rows. So, I want to hide all the empty rows in the `UItableview`.
2. Based on the non-empty rows, I want to change the height of my `UItableView`.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You sure you are using `UITableViewStyleGrouped` style?

Because by default it is set to `UITableViewStylePlain` which shows empty cells too after displaying filled cells.

Comment: Just this one simple change lets me avoid the always hacky feel of using a single space String as a section header title as well as removing the empty cells. How am I just finding out about this now??

Comment: Unfortunately this causes Xcode 9 to crash, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46390437/xcode9-0-in-storyboard-when-i-toggle-tableview-style-to-grouped-xcode-crashed

Answer (score 82):

**NEW ANSWER**

In Swift 2.2, 3.0 and onwards, do the following:

`tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()`

**OLD ANSWER BELOW. KEPT FOR POSTERITY.**

If you must use `UITableViewStylePlain`, and you don't use a footerView for anything else, you can use the following semi-dirty solution if you have ARC **enabled**.:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];

    return view;
}
```

If you have ARC **disabled**, use the following:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];

    return view;
}
```

This creates an invisible footerView, that appears immediately after the last data-filled cell.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but you were leaking memory by allocating a new view and passing that off, so I inserted an autorelease in there. If this was ARC-enabled code, I apologize, but someone complained about it leaking in practice, so I wanted to secure against that.

Comment: Sure, no problem. I tend to write my answers in ARC-enabled fashion. I'll make it known in my future posts that I'm writing in such a manner. 

Thanks for the heads up on the edit.

Comment: Note that the last time I checked, 93% of all iOS devices were running 6.0 or higher so there really is no reason to write non-ARC-enabled code anymore.

Comment: I agree with you, but the case was different 10 months ago, which is why Brad decided to change my code and add the autorelease syntax.

Comment: Yep, understood. It was more a hint that maybe it's time to change it back :D.

Comment: Awesome. Here is the swift code related to it: 
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = UIView()
        return view
    }

Comment: **SWIFT 3.0** works great with `tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()`

Answer (score 34):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section 
 { 
     return 0.01f;
 }
```

and for iOS 7

```
 self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Answer (score 17):

I solved the problem by creating a simple UIView as footer view with the same background color as the table background:

```
(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)] autorelease];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    return view;
}
```

Maybe you have to disable scrolling in your table view in addition.

Answer (score 11):

If your tableview has multiple sections, you may try using this:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == tableView.numberOfSections - 1) {
        return [UIView new];
    }
    return nil;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == tableView.numberOfSections - 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This can also be done through Interface Builder.  Simply add a 1 pixel tall UIView as a footer to the UITableView.  It's essentially the same as most of the answers here, but it keeps some UI specifics in the view instead of in the view controller.

[image]

Comment: +1 - I really like this zero code solution as it is inline with the premise of encapsulation.

Answer (score 6):

```
[self.SomeTableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

Use this to get rid of the lines if the `UITableView` is empty.

Comment: Switching from UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine to UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone depending on data availability did the trick for me. Much easier than previously listed answers!

Comment: The best solution! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

in the method that returns the number of rows, specify the `count` yourself dynamically. For example if you are going to populate the table with say a `NSArray` named `arrayForRows:`

```
return [arrayForRows count]; // inside the method which returns the number of rows.
```

The above is a simple example populating a table with an array as a datasource. There are no empty rows. Only that many rows show up in the table according to the `count` of items in the array populating the table.

I think you mean height of the row in the table. You can play around with the height of the rows by using the method:

```
(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView  *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
```

read http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

EDIT: ah now I get what you are trying to achieve. You are trying to avoid showing the empty rows separated with those separator lines right? See this post:

[how to display a table with zero rows in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491033/how-to-display-a-table-with-zero-rows-in-uitableview)

Comment: well, i would like you to check the same example on your end.My array returns only count 1. and there is only one row which has the data and under that there are 9 empty rows.I want to hide those empty rows.
and also i did not mean the row height. the table height. that is okay, i can take of that. But my 1st question still remains unanswered.

Comment: check the EDIT above. Is that what you are looking at? I used the same solution at my end to remove the lines. If I had 5 rows with data, the 5 would show up but the rest of the table in the screen had line separators. The only way out is a grouped table style instead of plain (unfortunately that defeated the purpose of my data view).

Comment: HI..i am not talking about edit.... when the viewdidload happens, you know that table will be loaded. By default all the empty rows will be created. if you specify the no.of rows in section, that many times cellforedit delegate willl be exeecuted and creates the cell content.But you can see there are other empty rows created. i want to remove those rows at some particular event.

Comment: so in a way you want the plain table style to look like a grouped one? if there are 5 items in your datasource array for instance, then the table must show only 5 line separated rows? In that case a workaround might be to make it a grouped style tableview with just one section and number of rows as indicated by the count of your datasource

Answer (score 0):

A bit hidden in Bourne's answer; if you want to hide to bottom empty rows in a plain tableview with multiple sections, use this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5658100/580173

Answer (score 0):

For Swift:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zeroRect)

// OR 

    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
}
```

For C#: (Please don't forget to add   `using CoreGraphics;` )

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
    this.sampleTableview.TableFooterView = new UIView(frame: CGRect.Empty);
}
```