# How to remove extra rows in a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xcode4

I have a `UITableView` which I am loading it with `NSMutableArray`. I want the extra rows to be removed i.e I want only the count number of objects in the `array` to be displayed as rows. If I have 3 objects in the `array` I want only 3 rows to be displayed in `UITableView`.But I can see the extra empty rows are also added in addition to the count number of objects in the `array`.How can I do it?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213197/how-to-hide-empty-rows-in-a-uitableview-and-change-the-height-of-the-uitableview

Comment: you can change your tableview frame if you have limited row...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use it may be helpful for you :)**

```
 - (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        // This will create a "invisible" footer
        return 0.01f;
    }

    - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        // To "clear" the footer view
        return [[UIView new] autorelease];
    }
```

**OR Use it.....**

```
     self.tblView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,370) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tblView.delegate=self;
    self.tblView.dataSource=self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tblView];

    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 10)];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.tblView setTableHeaderView:v];
    [self.tblView setTableFooterView:v];
    [v release];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve something like this:

> [image]

then check this tutorial out:
http://shiki.me/blog/removing-extra-separator-lines-for-empty-rows-in-uitableview

> To remove lines from empty rows, you just have to supply a value for tableFooterView. An empty UIView will work fine:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: shikii.net is no longer registered, so this answer is now useless

Comment: @ColinNicholson: I've updated the link (they seem to have changed the domain name to shiki.me) and added the example code to the answer too here just in case...

Answer (score 0):

You can add an empty footer view to your `UITableView` that should hide any additional 'blank' table view rows.

Answer (score 0):

Decrease the Height of the `UITableView`, works when you want to hide the extra rows and only want to show the specific rows. Make the height of the table dynamic .

See this link [Decrease Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213197/how-to-hide-empty-rows-in-a-uitableview-and-change-the-height-of-the-uitableview)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in couple of ways :

```
1) You can change your TableView type to UITableViewStyleGrouped
2) Either you can add a UIView in the Footer of UITableView keeping the UIView height to Zero. Incase if using UITableViewStylePlain
```

So, it depends on the type of your TableView how you wish to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   CGFloat number = 0.0;

   if (indexPath.row <= [yourArray count]) {

   number = 50.0; //or whatever value

 }
   return number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also work around solution.

You can set height of tableview to number of count in your array.

for example it will be `[array count]*[tableviewcell heigth]`

Hope this helps you....