# xcode9.0, in storyboard, when I toggle tableview style to grouped, xcode crashed

Tags: tableview, xcode9

In xcode9.0, I add a tableview to storyboard, when I toggle tableview style to grouped, xcode crash.

Comment: This is why i never update my xcode. the only way to do here is report a bug in apple website.

Comment: GOD I HATE XCODE. This is ridiculous!

Comment: FYI, I am experiencing the same thing in a XIB.

Opening it as source code and manually changing the table view's style to "grouped" makes it so that I cannot open the XIB until I change it back to "plain".

FWIW, Xcode has been mostly stable for me, although I suppose it's possible that this is a High Sierra issue (10.13 has not been very stable, in my experience).

Comment: It's Oct 19, 2017 now. Still having this issue, with both Xcode 9 and High Sierra updated to stable releases.

Answer (score 4):

1. Drag a new tableview to the top of the view
2. Remove the default check of the Automatic RowHeight and Automatic Estimate
3. Select  Group Type
4. OK

Comment: This works, but you can't switch back to "automatic" after that…

Answer (score 0):

I update to Xcode9.0.1, this problem has been solved.