# how to get the datatable view that is used in Alarm application in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone development. I am trying to develop an alarm app, same as in the iphone itself. But I am struggling to get to display the view of the table that shows only the filled in rows. I get the datatable all over the view.
  which property on the datatable decides to show only the filled in rows.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a custom UITableView, I would look at [this example](http://go2.wordpress.com/?id=725X1342&site=gregorykaiser.wordpress.com&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcocoawithlove.com%2F2009%2F04%2Feasy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) for more help on customizing UITableViews and UITableViewCells.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what i wanted. I can make the datatable look as i would like.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'll want to set your table style to "grouped".

[How can I set a UITableView to grouped style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006663/how-can-i-set-a-uitableview-to-grouped-style)

Then you'll need to make sure you're implementing the following function in your table view controller.  This will give you 3 rows in this example.

```
// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 return 3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.It was the datatable with the image view which resolved my problem.