# Can't reach navigationController, but should be able to. Can you spot the error?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Here's my MainWindow.xib. It contains a tab bar, the entries of which contain a UINavigationController each. Both CalendarViewController and SettingsViewController have no associated nibs.

[image]

From inside CalendarViewController, I can access `self.navigationController` just fine, but not from SettingsViewController. There, `self.navigationController` always returns `nil`.

What could I have forgotten? The view controller itself works just fine, btw.

Comment: Nothing wrong there, but somehow you are pushing SettingsViewController from a view controller which has no navigationController. Maybe you should post the initialization of the tab bar controller in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, or how you are reaching the SettingsViewController.

Comment: Ha! I had a custom initWithCoder method in SettingsViewController that somehow prevented the correct initialization. Do you want to post your comment as an answer so you can get honor, glory and SO-points?

Comment: Compare the comment on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006663/how-can-i-set-a-uitableview-to-grouped-style/6163249#6163249

Comment: You can accept your own answer, mine wasn't complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution (Thanks to Jano): My `initWithCoder:` method looked like this:

```
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    return self;
}
```

This didn't read the values represented in aDecoder and thus didn't initialize the `navigationController`property. I replaced it with this bit of code:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    return self;
}
```