# Programmatically create a grouped-style UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am creating tableView programmatically i want to set tableView style group but how to give that tableView alloc has only frame how we can set this values.

Comment: Use UITableViewStyleGrouped ....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set a UITableView to grouped style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006663/how-can-i-set-a-uitableview-to-grouped-style)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

refer a following code.

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,your_width,your_height) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

Answer (score 2):

you can programmatically add it by this way

```
tableView = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped] autorelease];
tableView.dataSource = self;
tableView.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:tableView];
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, whether  I understood your question in the right way, but you can construct a groupe tableView in this way:

```
UITableView* tview = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:yourFrame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```