# How to convert UITableView style programmatically from plain to group

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have added a plain UITableView in my viewcontroller. Now I need to show both plain and group tableview in the same view controller for different criteria.

How can I convert the UITableView's style from plain to group in the same viewcontroller?

Comment: see this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006663/how-can-i-set-a-uitableview-to-grouped-style

Answer (score 5):

If you are inheriting UITableViewController, you can just init tableView again.

Objective C:

```
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

Swift 4:

```
self.tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect.zero, style: .grouped)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need same UITableView for both Grouped and Plain table then you can create it programmatically like

In Objective-C

```
UITableView *myTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

In Swift

```
let tableView = UITableView.init(frame: CGRect.zero, style: .grouped)
```

else you can add two different UITableViews.